# How can I use CSS or Javascript to switch images on mouseover as simple and lightweight as possible?

Tags: javascript, css, mouseover

I'm trying to change one image to another on mouseover.  Specifically, when the visitor hovers over this:

[image]

The image will change to this:

[image]

**The Current Code**

I'd like to do this as lightweight as possible.  But the image-background CSS thing doesn't work for me.  My code is as follows:

```
<div id="featured-box-right"><a href="/videos/"  
target="_self"><img src="../images/box-featured-home-right.png" title="videos" 
alt="videos" width="300" height="150"></a></div>
```

But when I do this to the CSS:

```
#featured-box-right a:hover
{
background-image: url(../images/box-featured-home-right-hover.png); 
}
```

The effect doesn't turn out right; it's not a background.  It's an actual image.  Any guidance as to how I can achieve this as lightweight as possible would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would prefer to use sprite images rather than mouse hover as it reduces page loading time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lightweight method is to use CSS, and use the property `background-image` of the div:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/pRrhF/)

```
<div id="featured-box-right"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#featured-box-right {
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/OywDf.png'); 
}

#featured-box-right:hover {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRJOk.png'); 
}
```

Comment: Perfect -- exactly what I needed, Toni!  Thanks a lot for taking the time to point out the answer and offer the fiddle.  I just added a cursor:pointer to the css, and it's precisely what I wanted.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You should use css image sprites techniques and do not use img tag here use css background property. You should try something below. you can use cllass or id or parent child relationship that is totally up to you.

```
<div id="featured-box-right">
 <a href="/videos/" target="_self" id="img1"></a>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
#img1
{
    background: url(../images/box-featured-home-right.png); 
}

#img1:hover
{
  background: url(../images/box-featured-home-right-hover.png); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Happy.  Toni laid it out just exactly how I wanted it ... basically using your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `<img/>` tag altogether and try this css.

```
#featured-box-right a {
  background-image: url(../images/box-featured-home-right.png); 
}
#featured-box-right a:hover {
  background-image: url(../images/box-featured-home-right-hover.png); 
}
```

Comment: Yes, Teddy ... exactly what I did, per Toni's advice.  Exactly what I wanted ... thanks for taking the time to respond!

Answer (score 1):

***`CSS Sprites` is a technique where you use a `background-image`, a set width and height, and adjust the background-position to display only the portion you need to show. This way you can use a single image and display lots of different graphics with it, saving `server requests` and speeding up `page load` times***:

HTML:

```
<img src="images/arrow-sprite.png" alt="arrow" class="clip pos-1" />
```

CSS:

```
.clip               { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }

.pos-1              { clip:rect(0 48px 48px 0); }
.pos-2              { clip:rect(0 96px 48px 48px); left: -48px; }
.pos-3              { clip:rect(48px 48px 96px 0); top: -48px; }
.pos-4              { clip:rect(48px 96px 96px 48px); top: -48px; 
                      left: -48px; }
```

Took from [here](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites-with-inline-images/)

Comment: Got it ... I think Toni's solution was perfect for what I needed, but I appreciate you taking the time to share the information. I'm always looking to sprite images and reduce http requests ... gotta keep those yslow, etc., scores up!  Thanks for the link, as well!

Comment: You're welcome Jason. Hope finally you got the solution that's what we need :)

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the `<img>` tag and use CSS background iamge method, but you need to combine the 2 pic into one (one on top and one on bottom)

next, you need to use this code:

```
#featured-box-right {
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    background-image: url(image url here) center top; 
}

#featured-box-right:hover {
    background-image: url(image url here) center bottom; 
}
```

Using this method makes you need only 1 image

Comment: Thanks Gamehelp.  That's essentially what I did, using the advice Toni gave me ... well, exactly what I did.  Appreciate you taking the time to help me out with this!

Answer (score 1):

No images (background or otherwise) are required.

This comes out to only 3.84% the size of your two images combined:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/gWytK/show/:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
	<head>
		<title></title>
		<style>
body {
	margin: 8px;
}
#links {
	list-style: none;
	margin: 0;
	padding: 0;
	display: block !important;
	display: inline-block;
	overflow: hidden;
}
#links li {
	float: left;
	width: 300px;
	height: 150px;
	overflow: hidden;
	background: #000000;
	border-radius: 20px;
}
#links a {
	display: block;
	font: bold 30px/30px 'comic sans ms', sans-serif;
	padding: 40px 66px 100px;
	color: #5496ff;
	text-decoration: none;
	text-transform: capitalize;
	text-shadow: 0 0 100px #ffffff, 0 0 100px #ffffff;
}
#links a:after {
	content: ' >>';
}
#links a:hover, 
#links a:focus {
	color: #1b1b1b;
	background: #5496ff;
	text-shadow: none;
}
		</style>
	</head>
	<body>
		<ul id="links">
			<li>
				<a href="videos/">Our video collection</a>
			</li>
		</ul>
	</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No `image` property in CSS. In order to get the desired effect you should replace it with `background-image` and delete the `img` tag from your HTML code.

```
#featured-box-right
{
  background-image: url(../images/box-featured-home-right.png); 
}

#featured-box-right:hover
{
  background-image: url(../images/box-featured-home-right-hover.png); 
}
```

Comment: My apologies, Yair ... I had background-image, but mistyped when I posted it.  Thanks for responding!